# Flutter Snackbar dismiss listener

Tags: dart, flutter

I was looking for a way to check if the `Snackbar` has been dismissed, either by the user or by the timeout stuff. I could't really get any listener of doing it.

This is what I got so far,

```
Scaffold.of(context)
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Title")))
    .closed
    .then((reason) {
  // snackbar is now closed
});
```

This is the one way around, I was looking for exact listener. I don't want any work around, like setting `duration` of `Snackbar` and then listening to it after the duration has passed.

Comment: it is not workaround: see [SnackBarClosedReason](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SnackBarClosedReason-class.html)

Comment: @pskink Yes, that is what I am using but the problem with this is when you press back button to close the screen then the reason block doesn't get called.

Comment: return something when you click the back button to detect that behaviour. Use return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return _doSomeChecks(context);
      },
      child: SafeArea(
     ...

Answer (score 10):

see full example below
I just wrapped `SnackBar` content with `WillPopoScope` and if the user pressed back button it will remove snackbar.
By default it will specify `SnackBarClosedReason.remove` reason

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('go to test page'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Test())),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('show snack'),
          onPressed: () => _showSnack(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnack(BuildContext context) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
                return true;
              },
              child: Text("Title"),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .closed
        .then((reason) {
      print('------------ $reason');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, It worked like charm. I was searching this solution for 2 days. Thanks again :)